# How to filter out duplicate records caused by a JOIN in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query that returns a list of phone numbers for a given customer. The users are able to search for a specific customer by entering any part of their address. The customer can have multiple phone numbers and addresses.

Here is an example of my query:

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer.CustomerNumber, ORDER BY PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber) RowNumber,
Customer.CustomerNumber,
PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber
FROM Customer
JOIN PhoneNumber ON PhoneNumber.CustomerId = Customer.Id
JOIN CustomerAddress on CustomerAddress.CustomerId = Customer.Id
```

Here is what this query is producing when I have a customer that has two phone numbers and two addresses:

```
RowNumber     CustomerNumber     PhoneNumber
1             1                  111-111-1111
2             1                  222-222-2222
3             1                  111-111-1111
4             1                  222-222-2222
```

My desired result would be something along these lines:

```
RowNumber     CustomerNumber     PhoneNumber
1             1                  111-111-1111
2             1                  222-222-2222
```

I can only produce the desired result above when I remove the join on the address table.

A user should be able to look up a customer by entering in any part of the address (ex: I want to show any user that has an address in Phoenix). While it isn't displayed in the result, it still should be filterable.

I think I am able to do something like this:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Test.CustomerNumber ORDER BY Test.PhoneNumber) RowNumber
FROM
(
   SELECT
   DISTINCT 
   CustomerNumber, 
   PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber
   FROM Customer 
   JOIN PhoneNumber ON PhoneNumber.CustomerId = Customer.Id 
   JOIN CustomerAddress ON CustomerAddress.CustomerId = Customer.Id 
) Test
```

Comment: Try adding fields from address to the result and see what duplicates there are. The database probably allows multiple addresses per customer.

Comment: Then remove the join to the Address table.  You are not using it anyway.

Comment: Any reason you don't use DISTINCT?

Comment: Or stick everything in a subquery with `GROUP BY` and do your `ROW_NUMBER()` on the results.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I need the address table because the user can look up a customer based on the address.

Comment: @SteveJ: RowNumber() is different for each row, so DISTINCT won't change that. I think I might be able to modify it to work that way.

Comment: Group by can help but what will you do with the duplicate address info you want to display? Pick the minimum? You should understand why there are duplicates first rather than code around them.

Comment: Then you need to include those columns or WHERE clauses in your question.  Otherwise you are asking us the wrong question and you are going to get answers that will not work very well for you.

Comment: @ferensilver; You can use CTE, get the distincts, then re-join and use row number, like what is suggested by JNevill.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I thought the original question covered it. The edited question explains it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You're not selecting any columns from the `CustomerAddress` table, so joining that table has only the effects of suppressing results for customers with no address and duplicating results for those with multiple addresses.

If you don't want either of those effects then don't join `CustomerAddress`.  If you want only the former then you'd be better off with a different approach, such as

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer.CustomerNumber,
    ORDER BY PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber) RowNumber,
  Customer.CustomerNumber,
  PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber
FROM
  Customer
  JOIN PhoneNumber ON PhoneNumber.CustomerId = Customer.Id
WHERE
  Customer.Id IN (SELECT CustomerId from CustomerAddress)
```

Presuming that `Customer.Id` is a primary key, that should produce duplicates only if duplicate phone numbers for a given customer are recorded in the `PhoneNumber` table.

Comment: I need it as an ability to search for a specific customer. The where clause is created when the search is performed. So a customer could search for any customer from Phoenix, AZ. So I need access to this table.

Comment: @ferensilver you can add address criteria in a `WHERE` clause in the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the join on address might affect the ability of users to search by address.  If that is the problem, change the query to use `exists`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustomerNumber ORDER BY pn.PhoneNumber) as RowNumber,
       c.CustomerNumber,
       pn.PhoneNumber
FROM Customer c JOIN
     PhoneNumber pn
     ON pn.CustomerId = c.Id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM CustomerAddress ca
              WHERE ca.CustomerId = c.Id AND
                    ca.address like '%@ADDRESS%'  -- this is just an example of searching logic
             );
```

Comment: Based on the modified question this seems like a good answer. If the duplicate addresses are because the database is storing billing and shipping addresses in the same table they might need to add this to the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Change your window function to partition by customer and phone number in a sub query.  I use this all the time to filter dupes.  Just set the partition by to your unique key.

`Select * from (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer.CustomerNumber, PhoneNumber PhoneNumber, ORDER BY PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber) RowNumber,
    Customer.CustomerNumber,
    PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber
    FROM Customer
    JOIN PhoneNumber ON PhoneNumber.CustomerId = Customer.Id
    JOIN CustomerAddress on CustomerAddress.CustomerId = Customer.Id)
Where RowNumber = 1`